# c++ regex pattern to check file extension

Tags: c++, regex

I want to check if a string ends with .h5 and tried the c++ regex class. But for any Input the regex_search function returns false. Other examples in the internet looks similar to my code below, so I do not understand whats going wrong.

What is wrong with my code? Thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

  std::string text = argv[1];

  std::regex rx(".*\\.h5$");
  bool found = std::regex_search(text.c_str(),rx);

  std::cout << text << std::endl;
  std::cout << "res: " << found << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: is there any function like regex match?

Comment: try adding a multiline modifer.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af78d2c4c9733fc8).

Comment: What's in argv[1] for example ? A path which includes backslashes and colons ?

Comment: You probably need to update your compiler, if you are still using gcc version < 4.9

Comment: Is the input path string quoted?

Comment: Why do you even need a regex to do it? Why not simply check if the filename ends with the given extension?

Comment: I also tried regex match with the same result. No path in the input and not quoted. The compiler version is 4.8.4 ...

Comment: Can you show us the exact contents of `text`?

Comment: @DerJFK _"The compiler version is 4.8.4 "_ That's probably the cause of your problems. As mentioned `std::regex` works with gcc 4.9 or higher.

Comment: if I build the exectuable just type "./pogramm test.h5" (of course without quotes)

Comment: btw, for simply checking the file extension, you could use `filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("."))`

Comment: Thanks @all ... so I will not use regex ,.... did not know that it is not working < 4.9

Comment: @DerJFK In case you're using MinGW gcc, there's a 4.9 version available for 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using just [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) ?

```
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string filename(argv[1]);
  std::string last = filename.substr(filename.length() - 3);

  return last == ".h5";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `regex_search` with `regex_match`

```
std::regex rx(".*\\.h5$");
bool found = std::regex_match(argv[1], rx);
std::cout << "Result: " << std::boolalpha << found << std::endl;
```